# Isotope jquery plugin doesn't show properly on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I implanted Isotope jquery plugin successfully but for some reason I get problem showing all the items when the page is loaded first time and it's only on Chrome.

You can see here what is happening http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15358757/sd.jpg, that elements are on top of each other. but when I press on PSDs and then back to All it shows properly.

I don't have a default height for the container because I want to to be dynamic.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is probably that Isotope is doing its thing before the images are loaded.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/images.html

> [In this demo] Isotope is triggered after all images are loaded with the imagesLoaded
>   plugin.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#imagesloaded_plugin

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded(function() {
  $container.isotope({
    // options...
  });
});
```

Comment: It is also worth noting that adding items after initializing isotope requires using the `insert` method, as detailed at http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#insert , otherwise you'll still have the issue with new items.

Comment: Not sure if OP had the plugin or not but I had to download imagesLoaded and load it along w/ Isotope.  https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded