# Isotope intermittently returns 0px height on div

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-isotope

My Isotope layout is returning 0px height on its container. Refreshing the page always resolves the problem.

Has anyone run into this?

Here is my Isotope:

```js
var $container = $('#Stream');
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.stream-items',
    transformsEnabled: false
});
```

It occurs consistently albeit intermittently on Chrome, Safari, and FF. By "intermittently" I mean that sometimes it's on the first load, others on the third, or fourth, but eventually always happens.

I'm running on jQuery Mobile and have tried loading it the various options (window.load, pageinit, etc) but it happens regardless.

So, any ideas are much appreciated including any hacks that will force a refresh which always fixes the problem.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Just noticed that resizing the window resets to 0px height too.

Comment: `Refreshing the page always resolves the problem` -- makes me think that you are running the above code in a `document.ready` event handler. If that's the case then you need to go to a delegated event handler for a jQuery Mobile pseudo-page-event.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks! Nope, but same problem there. It is now in '$(window).load(function() {' Yikes! Have no idea of how to make a _delegated event handler for a jQuery Mobile pseudo-page-event_. Way above my level.

Comment: You have an online sandbox or bare-bones jsfiddle so we can see your code and see it happen live in Chrome's devtools? Maybe, it's because you're dynamically creating your Isotope elements and the #container can't work out the height, because there is no content (yet) in it at a certain point in time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/9268284/963514 which relates to the most typical issue I mentioned above - content not available on layout.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into both tomorrow. Yes, the Isotope elements are being created dynamically with a YQL call.

Comment: Took a different route. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Isotope doesn't have enough time to calc the images.
So I use window.load instead. Works a treat:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // Gallery Isotope
    $(function(){
        var $container = $('#gallery');
        $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: 'li',
            masonry : {
                columnWidth : 320
            }
        });
    });
});
```