# Implementing Jquery Isotope on images added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-modules, jquery-isotope

I am trying to write a module for Drupal which would have the functionality to handle images using isotope. What I am trying to do is taking an input link from user, then loading that image in #content-images div. I am facing problems in implementing isotope plugin on those images.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xu4k7/1/ for my code.
When I change the above code to the following code, images do not show up.

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#input-box-to-obtain-image-links").change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $('#content-images').append('<div class="image"><img class="isotope-images" src="'+value+'"></div>');
    });

     $('#content-images').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.image'
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

I just want to know how can I implement isotope on those images so that when I resize my browser, images align themselves.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your isotope wrapper has a 0px height, that's why images are not visible. Maybe isotope init is done too early, so it can't compute its wrapper height ? See

[Isotope jquery plugin doesn't show properly on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267844/isotope-jquery-plugin-doesnt-show-properly-on-chrome/9268284#9268284)

or

[Isotope intermittently returns 0px height on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942224/isotope-intermittently-returns-0px-height-on-div)

(first link really seems to be your solution : put isotope init in a callback fired after the actual DOM update)

Comment: Hello @user2295549! Thanks for replying. I have modified the core to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xu4k7/9/
It is working now! :)